# Fetching longitude and latitude from the database

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysqli

i want the locations variable to fetch longitude and latitude from the database the clusters them to be displayed
please need help on this i want all long and latitude to be fetched from the database which has a table that stores those data

```
<script>

  function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      //mkoa wa dodoma location
      center: {lat: -6.1630, lng: 35.7516}
    });

    // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    // Add some markers to the map.
    // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
    // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
    // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        label: labels[i % labels.length]
      });
    });

    // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
  }
   //kwajiri ya miji
  var locations = [
    {lat: -6.1730, lng: 35.7516},
    {lat: -6.2330, lng: 35.7523},
    {lat: -6.2330, lng: 35.7523},
    {lat: -6.2330, lng: 35.7523},
    {lat: -6.2330, lng: 35.7523},
    {lat: -6.1730, lng: 35.7516},
    {lat: -6.1730, lng: 35.7516},
    {lat: -7.773094,lng: 35.699120},
    {lat: -7.773094,lng: 35.699120},
    {lat: -7.773094,lng: 35.699120},
    {lat: -5.030461,lng: 32.819431},
    {lat: -5.030461,lng: 32.819431},
    {lat: -5.030461,lng: 32.819431},
    {lat: -5.030461,lng: 32.819431},
    {lat: -8.909401,lng: 33.460773},
    {lat: -8.909401,lng: 33.460773},
    {lat: -8.909401,lng: 33.460773},
    {lat: -6.802353,lng: 39.279556},
    {lat: -6.802353,lng: 39.279556},
    {lat: -6.802353,lng: 39.279556},
    {lat: -6.802100,lng: 39.279119},
    {lat: -6.1730, lng: 35.7516}
  ]
</script>
```

as you can see the variable location is in array

Comment: your question is incomplete, tell us what you have done for far, and what do you want to do with it.

Comment: i have updated it please check

Comment: you have to provide table sample also the way the lat and long data is stored in your table, also your PHP code. It is javascript are you using AJAX? or you want to fetch after posting form.

Comment: i want to use Ajax to fetch the data from the db but the structure from the database is has ID LONGITUDE LATITUDE

Comment: i only want to modify the variable locations only has the long and lat must no be static i want the variable to fetch those to fields from the database @SayedMohdAli

Answer (score 0):

Client-side script AJAX-call could look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : "https://epicsite.com/getLocations.php",
    success : function (data) 
    {
        if(data.error) {
            console.log(data.error);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            callFunctionToAddMarkersToMap(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Server-side script could look something like this:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"locations");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM locations";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    mysqli_close($con);

    return $result;
?>
```

So first in your client-side script you want to call that AJAX-route that will fetch marker coordinates. Then it will call function `callFunctionToAddMarkersToMap(data)` and you pass query result as a parameter. Then in the function you just loop given query result and add markers to the map.

Comment: @pangrasmwanossa Yes

Comment: still failed to implement @mpak